# Filter string in jsp not working with bracket [ ]

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I have a jsp page that sends a request to the servlet to filter the results of a column in a table based on a selected drop down value, which is populated by an SQL query to the MSSQL database. Right now I'm running into the issue where one of the items in the dropdown has the bracket ( something[something] ) and for some reason, when I select that item and filter the table, it will return no result even though clearly there's rows of data displayed with that item before the filter. Here's what I have now on the jsp page for the filter drop down:

```
<select title="Something Filter" name="${MODULE.REQUEST_SOMETHING}"
    id="${MODULE.REQUEST_SOMETHING}" tabindex="30"
    onkeydown="typeSelect(this, -1, 'xbin', 1);" onchange="clearTTID();"
    onblur="clearTTID();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.something}" var="row">
        <option value="${row.something}"
            <c:set var="setSelected" value="${row.something }" />
            <c:if test="${requestScope.something eq setSelected}">selected</c:if>
        >${row.something}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

All other items works fine, with just text, numbers, or parentheses, the filter will filter the table by those items as intended.

Comment: Can you post your SQL?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the open bracket `[` by using `[]`. So if you looking for a name `t[t]`, your query would be

```
select * from student where name like '%t[[]t]%'
```

**Update**

The second way is using escape option on the open bracket `[` (which is new to me, WOOHOO)

```
select * from student where name like '%t\[t]%' escape '\'
```